# MakeTextUppercase broke for cyrillic

Tags: cyrillic, bugs, uppercase, textcase

After the last TeXLive 2022 update, I was disappointed with the `\MakeTextUppercase` macro from `textcase` package for Cyrillic. I don’t understand what the conflict is, the package `textcase` has not been updated since 2019?

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex    
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{textcase}


\begin{document}

    \MakeTextUppercase{Efficiency}
    
    \MakeTextUppercase{Ефективність} % Wrong
    
    \MakeUppercase{Ефективність}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well the problem is that it hasn't been updated yet. But you don't really need it anymore, the standard \MakeUppercase has been improved.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. But it is surprising that the problem somehow spontaneously manifested itself after last update.

Comment: latex has been updated and as I wrote it changed something here.

Comment: https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/tree/main/textcase  the  last commit is in Feb "future UTF-8 handling "  But it appears the future has arrived... You should be able to use the version from there, I'll do some checks and arrange an update a ctan. Sorry about that

Comment: You can replace `\usepackage{textcase}` by `\let\MakeTextUppercase\MakeUppercase` as `textcase` isn't needed now

Comment: I pushed a new version to ctan just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LaTeX releases starting from June 2022, `\MakeUppercase` is an improved version of the `\MakeTextUppercase` command provided by `textcase`: it avoids math in the same way but has improved Unicode support, being based on the `expl3` case changing functions.

A new version of `textcase` has been released that does nothing in current LaTeX other than alias the old package command name `\MakeTextUppercase` to `\MakeUppercase` (and similarly for lowercase).

An unfortunate error in scheduling meant that the `textcase` update was a couple of days after the LaTeX release, meaning it had broken behaviour, as reported here, during that time. It should now work as advertised, but shouldn't be used for new documents, simply use the standard LaTeX commands.